# SQL Server - Display name value pairs as columns?

Tags: sql-server, json

I have tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE case_form 
(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO case_form (id, title, description)
VALUES (1, 'test', 'test')

CREATE TABLE case_fields 
(
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    value TEXT NOT NULL,
    case_form_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX FK__case_form (case_form_id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_case_form FOREIGN KEY (case_form_id) REFERENCES case_form 
)

INSERT INTO case_fields (name, value, case_form_id)
VALUES ('type', 'Request', 1), ('category', 'Sales', 1)
```

I want to create a view or generate a query for the `case_form` table that will include all name value pairs as columns as follows:

```
id  | title | description | type    | category
----+-------+-------------+---------+------------
1   | test  |  test       | Request | Sales
```

The following query doesn't give me the above output but give the following:

```
select t1.*, t2.name, t2.value 
from case_form t1
inner join case_fields t2 on t2.case_form_id = t1.id
```

Output:

```
id  | title | description | name    | value
----+-------+-------------+---------+---------
1   | test  |  test       | type    | Request
1   | test  |  test       | category| Sales
```

Should I be perhaps be storing the name value pairs as a json object maybe in the `case_form` table as follows:

```
{ 
  type: "Request",
  category: "Sales",
  team: "abc"
}
```

How would I query this to give me a table view similar to the above?

The reason for this structure is so that I can create dynamic forms in a .Net MVC application

Any helps tips guidance appreciated

Comment: what output is coming from above query?

Comment: you table definition is for `MySQL` but since you have tagged your question as `sql-server`, I have provided answer for `tsql`.

Comment: @AB_87 yes the definition is for mysql but its going to be migrated to sql server so need answer for sql server.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @adam78 Query I posted provides the result you have mentioned. Did it not resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to `pivot` you data. Below query gives the result you have mentioned:

```
select * from 
(select t1.id, t1.title, CAST(t1.description as VARCHAR(MAX)) as [description], CAST(t2.name as VARCHAR(MAX)) as Name, CAST(t2.value as VARCHAR(MAX)) as value
from 
case_form t1
inner join case_fields t2 on t2.case_form_id = t1.id
) as t
pivot
( max(value)
for name in ([type],[category])
)as piv
```